# How to change sitecore's login page url /Sitecore/login

Tags: authentication, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I am using sitecore 8.1 and wants to change sitecore's default login url from http://domain/sitecore/login to http://domain/admin-login.
I don't wants to change the structure of physical file so i just updated below settings in App_Config/sitecore.config

`<site name="shell" ----- loginPage="/admin-login"  ------/>
<site name="login" virtualFolder="/admin-login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login"  ------/>`

now i can access login page by http://domain/admin-login but old path http://domain/sitecore/login still exist might be because of physical folder structure.

Any thoughts ? or best practices suggested by **sitecore** ?

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server#_How_to_configure and https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/restrict_access_to_the_client

Comment: @JanBluemink we have followed these instructions for content delivery server which is perfect. our authoring server would be ip restricted in future. but these docs does give answer to my question :)

Comment: ok, It is because of I'm missing the why question, for the security you do so.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are still able to access the "old location" is due to the `/sitecore/login` folder on disk (which loads the `default.aspx` file located in that folder).

I would be careful about changing the name/location of this folder since there is hardcoded references to this in the Sitecore Kernel, such as redirects when session expires.

Comment: And in the web.config file: ErrorPage, NoAccessUrl, NoLicenseUrl, LayoutNotFoundUrl, ItemNotFoundUrl, LinkItemNotFoundUrl are default point to the /sitecore folder but that is easy to change.

Comment: @jammyKam you are right that's why i don't wants to change or delete the folder structure but just restrict access to default login page.
I guess IIS redirection would do a trick ?

Comment: Yes, you can restrict access in IIS or use some IIS redirect rules on your CD servers.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply comment the entry of the login in the `<sites>` tag since you are already creating a new site definition in a config file.

The reason why you are still having access to the sitecore/login is because in the sites section, it will contain both sitecore/login and /admin-login.

If you check the showconfig, you will see both entries.

Comment: That's not quite true, the `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.FileResolver` will check if a matching file for a request exists  on disk, and if so `ExecuteRequest` hands control to that file. Since `/sitecore/login` exists on disk, changing config settings for this will not work.

Comment: I've tried commenting the sitecore/login from the web.config and use the admin-login. It worked. However, when accessing the sitecore/login, i got an error. So i think commenting the /sitecore/login will work.

Comment: You'll still be able to login via `/sitecore/admin/login.aspx` and have access to all the security tools (e.g. `dbbrowser.aspx`).